# Keycloak : Get notified via API when a new user registers

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I have an Angular (client-side) Java Spring Boot 2 (server-side) application that redirects to Keycloak in order for the user to perform their authentication / registration etc. And after the users logs in, they are redirected to the application with their token.

I want to know (on the Java server-side) when a user registers, so that I can create some extra things in my own database for them. Is there a standard way to "listen" to when a user registers on my Keycloak? Any example for such behavior in Java?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keycloak provide for you option to implement [EventListenerSPI](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_events), but i'm not sure that there is an appropriate event type for finished registration, so it would be better for you to implement [custom registration step](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#modifying-extending-the-registration-form). After implementation you could put it to the end of registration flow (Authentication settings section in admin console) and perform your tasks in external DB.